Jamf return to service wifi configuration
I am currently working on the Jamf mdm return to service command attempting to erase device and have the mac automatically set up without user intervention.
I have tested with the Jamf swagger api. And have successfully erase the device. Yet, the wifi profile data did not load by itself. Therefore, it fails to connect to the wifi and cannot do the enrollment itself.
I don’t know am I missing any necessary steps or api roles and clients authentication or does it just work on mobile device.
  pro.create_mdm_command(
        {
            "commandData": {
                "commandType": "ERASE_DEVICE",
                "returnToService": {
                    "enabled": True,
                    "mdmProfileData": "iamnotshowingthisbutididbase64encodeit",
                    "wifiProfileData": "iamnotshowingthisbutibase64encodeit"
                },
                "pin": "123456"
            },
            "clientData": [{ "managementId": " -6043-4dae-8341-265768a15e5f" }]
        }
    )

This is written in python. With a jamf wrapper. But both of the api were only able to erase the device only.
The following steps were taken:
Setup wifi profile in Jamf
Download the wifi profile mobile.config turn it into xml format
Use base64 to encode the xml
By using the jamf api swagger, authenticate the user.
Get the jamf management id
Plug everything in with a shell script.
Erases device, fails to have wifi configured.
Does anyone know a solution or encountered similar problem can provide some guidance. Thank you.

If you erase the device you delete all profiles,
You would still have to manually go through the first few Mac setup steps until a connection is set up to get the Jamf profiles and load the rest of the profiles from the Jamf console.
I keep a local simple wifi in the lab for the initial setup.

Read this again and noted that you said Mac. It looks like Return to Service is only available for iOS and iPadOS version 17+, not macOS:

Use the returnToservice option to instruct iOS or iPadOS devices to
automatically reconnect to Wi-Fi after erasure and re-enroll with Jamf
Pro. Return to Service eliminates the need to manually guide an erased
device through certain Setup Assistant screens that could previously
not be skipped, including the screens for setting the language and
region, and connecting to Wi-Fi.

https://learn.jamf.com/en-US/bundle/technical-articles/page/Return_to_Service.html
Additionally, they have to be enrolled via Automated Device Enrollment through ABM/ASM, and Activation Lock must be disabled.
It looks like you are trying to do this on an unsupported device.
